# Does the wait() function return before SIGCHLD is handled?

Tags: c, signals

So I have a custom handler for SIGCHLD and a wait() function. The child will exit after the parent sends it the signal SIGUSER2. In this example when the child calls "exit(0)" will the parent handle SIGCHLD and exit or is it possible for the "wait()" function to return before the SIGCHLD signal is handled?

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<wait.h> 
#include<signal.h> 
pid_t pid; 
int counter = 0; 
void handler1(int sig) 
{ 
    printf("A\n");
    kill(pid, SIGUSER2);
} 
void handler2(int sig) 
{ 
    printf("B\n");
    exit(0); 
} 

int main() 
{ 
    signal(SIGUSR1, handler1);
    signal(SIGCHLD, handler2); 
    if ((pid = fork()) == 0) 
    { 
        signal(SIGUSR1, handler2);
        kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1); 
        while(1) ; 
    } 
    if ((p = wait(&status)) > 0) 
    { 
        printf("wait returned before SIGCHLD");
    } 
}
```

Comment: My own personal maxim -- and I'm sorry, this will probably sound like unhelpful advice -- is that I *never* try to catch SIGCHLD, and the reason is that there are so many race conditions and imponderable questions surrounding it, such as the one you've asked.  (Even if someone claims to have a definitive answer, I don't trust it -- it's too likely to change in the next version, or something.)

Comment: @SteveSummit But the program doesn't catch SIGCHLD.

Comment: 1) `sig_atomic_t` 2) dont use stdio inside signal handlers.

Answer (score 1):

From the manpage for `wait`, it can get `EINTR`:

> EINTR  WNOHANG  was  not  set  and an unblocked signal or a SIGCHLD was caught

So, if `SIGCHLD` has a handler, and you're in `wait`, the signal will happen *first*.

This is what makes sense. Because, `SIGCHLD` handlers are a liberty to do a `wait` to reap the child. Some programs *don't* do `wait` in baseline code, but rely on the handler.

As others have mentioned, don't do `printf` in a handler [it does `malloc` and all bets are off].  However, doing a `wait` is okay [*some* syscalls are okay/allowed in a handler].

Your program had a few issues. I refactored it a bit. It shows that the `SIGCHLD` occurs *before* the `wait` completes [as the man page implies].

Note that this is pretty good test, but a definitive one might involve a *third* process that has to kill the original child (*after* a small sleep) to allow the parent to enter the `wait`.

That is, the `kill` will happen (in process 3), after the main process has entered `wait`.

I didn't do that, so here's the simpler version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <wait.h>
#include <signal.h>

pid_t pid;
volatile int gotsig = 0;

void
handler_cld(int sig)
{
    gotsig = 1;
}

void
handler_usr1(int sig)
{
    exit(0);
}

int
main()
{
    int status;

    signal(SIGUSR1, handler_usr1);
    signal(SIGCHLD, handler_cld);

    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        while (1);
    }

    // kill the child
    kill(pid,SIGUSR1);

    if ((pid = wait(&status)) > 0) {
        printf("wait returned %s SIGCHLD\n",gotsig ? "after" : "before");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Here's the more elaborate version that uses the separate "killer" process to kill the child, but the results are the same:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <wait.h>
#include <signal.h>

volatile int gotsig = 0;

void
handler_cld(int sig)
{
    gotsig += 1;
}

void
handler_usr1(int sig)
{
    exit(0);
}

int
main()
{
    int status;

    signal(SIGUSR1, handler_usr1);
    signal(SIGCHLD, handler_cld);

    pid_t pidcld = fork();
    if (pidcld == 0) {
        while (1);
    }

    pid_t pidkill = fork();
    if (pidkill == 0) {
        sleep(1);
        // kill the child
        kill(pidcld,SIGUSR1);
        sleep(3);
        exit(0);
    }

    pid_t pidany;

    // wait for child
    if ((pidany = waitpid(pidcld,&status,0)) > 0) {
        printf("wait on child returned %s SIGCHLD\n",
            gotsig ? "after" : "before");
    }

    // wait for child
    if ((pidany = waitpid(pidkill,&status,0)) > 0) {
        printf("wait on killer returned %s SIGCHLD\n",
            gotsig ? "after" : "before");
    }

    return 0;
}
```